# JSON.parse gives unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I receive this data when I call my api

```
[{"DispatchNo":"xxxxx","DispatchDate":"xxxxxxx","Complete":"xxx","CustomerID":"xxxxx","Name":"xxxxxx","Contact":"","Phone":"xxxxx","ShipPhone":"xxxx","PurchaseOrder":"xxxx","OrderLoads":"5","OrderQty":"125","FreightUnitID":"x
```

my controoller.js code where it indicates failure is:

```
var jsonString = result.data.replace(/\\/g, "\\");
                var orderFromApex = JSON.parse(jsonString);
                orderFromApex = orderFromApex.substring(0);
                console.log(orderFromApex);
                //orderFromApex += '"';
                orderFromApex = JSON.parse(orderFromApex);
                console.log(orderFromApex);
```

I get error SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 898
    at JSON.parse () I believe it is failing at orderFromApex = JSON.parse(orderFromApex). I am also console logging orderFromApex which I have posted above. What is going on? is there a problem with my JSON response?

Comment: The JSON has some unescaped `"`'s, which makes it invalid. Specifically the portion: `"comment3":"door to office "Call derek before Dumping.""`

Comment: copy your json, go here: https://jsonlint.com/ and you will see that the problem is that you have an invalid json response at line 38

Comment: `orderFromApex.substring(0);` wat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your API seems to not escape characters correctly. `"` for example appears unescaped inside strings closing them before they should be closed.

`{"example": "Hello "World"!"}` should instead be `{"example": "Hello \"World\"!"}`.

Trying to parse the first example will throw `SyntaxError: Unexpected token W in JSON at position 20`. That's because the parser will look at the `"` before `World` and think *Oh, the string is already over, what's this weird `W` doing after it?*.

Comment: To be more clear the sentence `"Call derek before Dumping."` It breaks the logic and the parser is met with the unexpected character `C` ...`\"Call derek before Dumping.\"` should be returned instead.

Comment: I understand Thank you :)